# Transform ForeignKey into OneToOne field depending on current user

Tags: django, foreign-key-relationship, one-to-one

I have a setup like in the following (simplified) example:

```
class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Favorite(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='favorites')
    pizza = models.ForeignKey(Pizza, related_name='favorites')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('user', 'pizza'),)
```

I know that I can filter the `favorites` property on a `Pizza` model instance by the `user` property, but I'd like to abstract this.

In my application, a user should only have access to its personal `Favorite` model instances. To ensure this, I find myself having to filter all the time and do a lot of ugly and inefficient stuff.

I want to abstract this so that when a user is logged in, I should be able to access `pizza.favorite`, instead of `pizza.favorites`, which is automatically mapped to the current user's `Favorite` model for this particular `Pizza` model. Ideally, I should also be able to filter on this property (no possible with the @property annotation). Basically, it should act like the `ForeignKey` is now a `OneToOne` field.

Any ideas on how could I achieve this behaviour? I should note that un-authorized users do not concern me. The application does not provide anonymous access, so that edge case can be disregarded.

I am using Django 1.7 and I am also open to using the development version, if that would help.

Comment: Why not using `request.user.favorites.all()` or `request.user.favorites.all` in templates?

Comment: I have to do extensive filtering and/or ordering in the back-end on the current Favorite model, from the Pizza part, so to say. Also,  there are potentially a lot of Favorite models and there are definitely a lot of Pizza models and I should only work with the Favorite models that I'm concerned with at the moment, otherwise it becomes too slow.

Comment: I understood that fact. But what should be the result of `pizza.favorite`? I mean, if it is only one object, you don't need to filter it.

Comment: You did not fully understood. Pizza normally has the `favorites` property (note the plural). I want that field to be automatically filtered by the current user (there's only one pizza - user Favorite object) and replaced by `favorite`.

Comment: Then you should maybe use an `OneToOneField` for the user-favorite relation. Then you can do it by the user. I mean you want to get informations about the user and their favorite pizza. And if you want to get the favorite pizza for the current user, you always have the user object.

Comment: No, you got that wrong. For each Pizza, the user can have a single Favorite object. Note the `unique_together = (('user', 'pizza'),)`. So the User can have multiple Favorite objects (for different Pizzas) and I can't use a OneToOneField for the User - Favorite relation.